# Rhythmbox Refuses to start

Tags: rhythmbox, crash, timeout

I recently opened rhythmbox, tried to play a song, and it froze. I killed it, but now it won't start at all. Running from the terminal gives me `(rhythmbox:3676): Rhythmbox-CRITICAL **: Timeout was reached`. I have tried uninstalling and re-installing, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `sudo apt-get purge rhythmbox && sudo apt-get install rhythmbox` in an Terminal. This will delete the program and all the associated config files (including corrupt ones), and then reinstall a fresh copy of Rhythmbox. You'll need to setup everything with Rhythmbox again though

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problem, but it also started another. Running rhythmbox in the terminal gives me a seg fault `(rhythmbox:1625): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_builder_add_from_file: assertion 'filename != NULL' failed
Segmentation fault`
I've heard this is a problem with ubuntu one, but I'm not sure